# How to filter users based on address location?

Tags: 7, views, location

I have a content type "job". There is a field "location" which contains the zip code of area. Now i want to filter users based on distance from job's zip code. Each user also have a zip code. 
I already have a view which is filtering users on different criteria. Is there any way to achieve this in view?

***EDIT***
here is what exactly i needed. 
adding a job should have a field to add the zip code of the location of the job. This should change the way the users are filtered for the job as the customer should be able to filter the users using radius selector for 1 km, 5km, 10km, less than 50 km.
Thanks

Comment: You need to use something that does geolocation/proximity search. I thought Location module did this in 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for https://www.drupal.org/node/1944648

Answer (score 1):

You can use [geolocation_proximity](https://www.drupal.org/project/geolocation_proximity)